# Excel find 17 Cells with highest value, 5 of which are the highest in a specific row

Tags: excel

I'm struggling with a complex excel problem, and I would be amazed by any solution.

I have a table with 4 columns and the following values

```
The highest    |13|12|12|12|
The two highest|11|12|11|11|
The two highest|12|12|12|12|
               |12|11|11|11|
               |12|11|11|11|
               |12|11|11|11|
```

My problem requires from the first three rows to select the highest respectively the two highest values. Over the complete matrix there should be a sum of 12 values.

The required 5 plus whatever are the remaining 7 highest values. My current approach is to do a sum of the required rows and add the rest together, but that is obviouly not working.

```
|13|12|12|12|[MAX(B10:E10)]13|
|11|12|11|11|[LARGE(B11:E11;1)+LARGE(B11:E11;2)23|
|12|12|12|12|[LARGE(B12:E12;1)+LARGE(B12:E12;2)24|
|12|11|11|11|
|12|11|11|11|
|12|11|11|11|
```

Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated. Also a more understandable title for references would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: Of course that is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**
It's sloppy VBA, but this works and the structure is generally expandable if you need it to be. You can just paste this in a VBA module, run Sum57(), and the result will be in the debug window (Ctl + G). To modify this for other array sizes, change the following :

- the size of the `used` array in line 1
- the values of arrR and arrC in lines 5 and 6 which define the start of the array
- the pattern of the function calls in the body of `Sum57()`

The base pattern is:

```
   For i = 1 To N
       x = x + LargeOfRange([rStart], [rEnd], [cStart], [cEnd])
   Next
```

where N is top N largest numbers from the range.

---

**VBA:**

```
Public used(5, 3) As Boolean
Public arrR, arrC As Integer

Public Sub Sum57()
    arrR = 10
    arrC = 2
    For a = LBound(used, 1) To UBound(used, 1)
    For b = LBound(used, 2) To UBound(used, 2)
        used(a, b) = False
    Next
    Next

    Dim x As Integer

        x = x + LargeOfRange(10, 10, 2, 5)
    For i = 1 To 2
        x = x + LargeOfRange(11, 11, 2, 5)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 2
        x = x + LargeOfRange(12, 12, 2, 5)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 7
        x = x + LargeOfRange(10, 15, 2, 5)
    Next
    Debug.Print x
End Sub


Public Function LargeOfRange(rStart As Integer, rEnd As Integer, _
                             cStart As Integer, cEnd As Integer) As Integer
    On Error GoTo SkipVal
    Dim l, x, xR, xC As Integer
    x = 0

    For r = rStart To rEnd
        For c = cStart To cEnd
            If x < Cells(r, c).Value And used(r - arrR, c - arrC) = False Then
                xR = r
                xC = c
                x = Cells(r, c).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    used(xR - arrR, xC - arrC) = True
    LargeOfRange = x
Exit Function

SkipVal:
    LargeOfRange = 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just extend the range and add more elements to the Large() calc?

```
=LARGE(B13:E15,1)+LARGE(B13:E15,2)+LARGE(B13:E15,3)+LARGE(B13:E15,4)+
 LARGE(B13:E15,5)+LARGE(B13:E15,6)+LARGE(B13:E15,7)
```

This returns 80

Comment: Because the remaining 7 values should also come from other cells above, that haven't been 'used'.
You solution only accounts for the not used rows.
The solution should return 84. It should use the other 12s from the top, before added some of the 11s